# Do I qualify for unemployment benefits if I forgot to file in time, but now I have found a new job?

Tags: united-states, california, unemployment

I had lost my job in June 2019 but I missed on filling my claim in time (since I was busy looking for new jobs). I found a job, but would I still get unemployment from my time that I was unemployed, even though I forgot to file while I was unemployed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you failed to file, such as forgetting your weekly certification, then you do not get the money. Unfortunately, that's just the way it is.

Additionally, since you got a new job and are now employed, then you are not eligible for unemployment, since you are now employed. Sorry. I know it hurts that you were unemployed and still have backdated bills to pay, but hopefully you can make do until your new employment earns enough to bring you stable again.

Also, congratulations on your new employment!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that usually, you only qualify for unemployment benefits for the weeks starting with the week you filed the claim. So for example, if you qualified to file unemployment benefits 1 week after you lose your job, but you wait until 5 weeks after you lose your job to file the claim, then you only only get unemployment benefits that are for that 5th week (and 6th week and so on, assuming you remain eligible for unemployment benefits). You do not retroactively get the benefits for the first 4 weeks that you missed.

So if you filed a claim now, you would only get benefits for this week and onwards. But 1) I don't think unemployment benefits last for 11 months, and 2) you already got a job now, so you don't qualify for unemployment benefits now anyway. So you can't get any unemployment benefits now.

Comment: that's exactly what I already said in my answer.